# gradient of a differentiable concave function

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, vector-analysis

Let $f\colon [0,1]^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous, differentiable and concave function. Consider two arrays $\mathbf{z} = \{ z_1, \dots, z_n \} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{y} = \{ y_1, \dots, y_n \} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that it holds $\mathbf{z} \preceq \mathbf{y}$, i.e., $ z_i \leq  y_i $ for all $i = 1, \dots, n$. Prove that it holds $\nabla f(\mathbf{y}) \preceq \nabla f(\mathbf{z})$, i.e., $\frac{d}{dx_i}f(\mathbf{y}) \leq \frac{d}{dx_i}f(\mathbf{z})$ for all $i = 1, \dots, n$. If the claim is false, please provide a counterexample.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Generic hint: consider a toy example. Try $n=2$. Can you generate a counterexample? If not, why not? Does this work when $n=3$? In general?

Comment: Try $f(x)={1 \over 2} x^T A x$ with $A\le 0$ for suitable $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is a very simple counterexample. Let us consider

the function $f(x,y)=-x^{2}+xy-y^{2}$ which is clearly

concave. Let $z=(0,0)$. The gradient of $f$ is

$\bigtriangledown f(x,y)=$ $\begin{pmatrix}
-2x+y \\-2y+x
\end{pmatrix}$.  Let $(x,y)=(0,1)$. The gradient at zero is zero, but

$\bigtriangledown\,f(0,1)=$ $\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\-2
\end{pmatrix}$  is not $\leq$ $\begin{pmatrix}
 0\\0
\end{pmatrix} $ in the sense it is described in the question!!